# What is the average bandwidth used by the default client?

Tags: client, bandwidth

I am asking it because I'd like to install the client in my work office. Is that safe? I know the first time it take a long time downloading about 2 GB or more, but what is the daily normal activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100 MB per day, or less.

(i.e., a dial-up modem could handle it.)

Comment: But it is too much to keep up in work office.